# Phonegap App crashes after taking a photo on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, camera

phonegap 3.3.0
iOS7

After taking a photo and pressing the "Use this photo" button the screen turns black, and the app crashes.
Have put the image quality already under 50% to avoid memory problems.
But still this here won't work :(

Can anyone help?

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    var pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;


    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    var options = {
        quality: 40,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    };

    function capturePhoto() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, options);
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        $('body').append(
        '<p>Failed because: ' + message + '</p>');
    }


    $('#capturePhoto').click(function(){
        capturePhoto();
    });

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code once:-
 Also please check once whether you are done with the entry of Camera plugin in config.xml or not?

```
 <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
 </feature>

And check below code in your html page :-

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


function onDeviceReady() {
                                            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                                            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
                        }
/*open camera for capture photo*/
function capturePhoto() {
             largeImage.src='';
                                 // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
                                         navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 75,
                                                                     destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI});

                               }

                              function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
                                     // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
                                     // Get image handle

                                           var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
                                         // Unhide image elements

                                             largeImage.style.display = 'block';
                                             // Show the captured photo
                                                 largeImage.src = imageURI;

                              }
```

Comment: great! works. Totally did not realize to put the CDVCapture feature into my XML-file!

Comment: The feature is not necessary if you are using the CLI. From https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File:  "If you use the CLI to build applications, you use the plugin command to enable device APIs. This does not modify the top-level config.xml file, so the <feature> element does not apply to your workflow."

Answer (score 1):

putting the CDVCapture feature into my XML made it!

quick other question...
what is the difference between

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

and

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

?

and i read that you should set the image quality under 50% to avoid crashing on some devices. do you know if this still is an issue?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to include a core plugin with your PhoneGap Build project, you can simply add the gap:plugin tag to your config.xml file.